# Similar software to Clarify

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for something similar to [Clarify](http://www.clarify-it.com/), but, for Ubuntu.

Is there one available?

Answer (score 4):

[shutter](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/shutter/), is one of the best. Feaure full and fast.

**Features**:

- take a screenshot of your complete desktop, a rectangular area or capture a website
- take screenshot directly or with a specified delay time
- save the screenshots to a specified directory and name them in a convenient way (using special wild-cards)
- Shutter is fully integrated into the GNOME Desktop (TrayIcon etc.)
- generate thumbnails directly when you are taking a screenshot and set a size level in %
- Shutter session collection
- keep track of all screenshots during session
- copy screeners to clipboard
- print screenshots
- delete screenshots
- rename your file
- upload your files directly to Image-Hosters (e.g. http://ubuntu-pics.de), retrieve all the needed links and share them with others
- edit your screenshots directly using the embedded drawing tool

**Install**

shutter is available in the official repo, from 13.10 and older. The shutter PPA supports all of them and newer versions of Ubuntu, therefore we will use the PPA as our main install method. You will also be updated via the Update Manager when you add the PPA.

**PPA**

For the latest version of shutter, add the [official ppa](https://launchpad.net/~shutter/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to your sources:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shutter/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

The ppa supports the following Ubuntu versions:

Utopic (14.10), Trusty (14.04), Saucy (13.10), Raring (13.04), Quantal (12.10), Precise (12.04), Oneiric (11.10), Natty (11.04), Maverick (10.10), Lucid (10.04), Karmic (9.10), Jaunty (9.04), Intrepid (8.10), Hardy (8.04), Gutsy (7.10).

**Screen-shot**:

[image]

Comment: @muru , forgot to edit that out. Second way was to install via the official repo. But, shutter is only available in the 13.10 repo and older. the ppa supports all of them and never Ubuntu versions. So, i removed the second part.

Comment: I know shutter but I want to create PDf or HTML with more scrennshots and describe.

Comment: @IceManSpy Copy paste the screen-shot in LibreOffice writer, and export it as `pdf`. You can also export it as `HTML`.

Comment: yes I know, that I can use Libre with screenshot, but I have to control myself to have the same style in whole document - Clarify does it automatically.